# How to insert a column vector on inputdlg using Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm new on Matlab. I'm going to use inputdlg command to create a dialog box in witch I introduce my input data. So I've a problem, my input data aren't scalar but column vectors:

ex.(my input data, t1,t2....are column vector of the txt file datigaressio.txt):

```
h=load('datigaressio.txt');
anni=h(:,1);

t1=h(:,2);

t3=h(:,3);

t6=h(:,4);

t12=h(:,5);

t24=h(:,6);
```

How can I insert this data on my dialog box?!

Answer (score 0):

INPUTDLG is used for very simple dialog window.

To show the table you will have to create a dialog window by yourself (see how to use [GUIDE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_guis/bqz6p81.html)) and show the data using [UITABLE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uitable.html).